# Retreving Array Element from Multiple Size array in GoogleSpreadSheet

Tags: multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This should be a very simple task, but for some reason I´m not seeing my mistake. I´m sorry if it is too obvious.

I have created an Array with multiple items inside it (it is the first log in the picture).
Some of this items are Arrays. I want to retrieve the first item from the first array.
It should be quite simple. The name of my Array is boardAsArray, so I should just type:

```
boardAsArray[1][0];
```

And since the second item of this array is an Array, I should get the first item of the array inside of the array. But this is not what´s happening.

Here is the picture of the logs:

[image]

Here is what I´ve asked the code to log (in this order):

```
Logger.log(boardAsArray);
Logger.log(boardAsArray[1]);
Logger.log(boardAsArray[1][0]);
Logger.log(boardAsArray[1][1]);
Logger.log(boardAsArray[1][2]);
Logger.log(boardAsArray[1][3]);
Logger.log(boardAsArray[1][4]);
Logger.log(boardAsArray[1][5]);
Logger.log(boardAsArray[1][6]);
```

As you can see in the picture. Instead of getting the first item of the first array, the code is logging the first array apparently as a string.

How do I fix this? What am I doing wrong?

I´m really sorry if this question is not very clear, but here is the thing. I´m don´t really understand what´s going on. It is so messy that I can´t even explain it...

Given this array (the first log in the picture):

```
Logger.log(boardAsArray[1][0])
// Should be 6 and not [
```

Sorry again for the confusion.
And thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the element `boardAsArray[1]` everything is a `string`. Hence `boardAsArray[1][0]` gives the value `[` and so on. Make sure that it is an array.

Comment: Is there a easy way of doing this?

In order to create boardAsArray, I used:

    boardAsArray.push(somearrayhere);

Could that be the problem?

Comment: check the type of `somearrayhere`? I need to see some code to be able to help. It seems `somearrayhere` is a `string`. Try logging the `typeof` `somearrayhere`.